# divide two DF count but getting 0 in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to divide two DF count but getting 0 I think I need to do typecasting. Can you help me.

```
val subscribed = dataDF.where("Y='yes'").count
subscribed: Long = 5289
val Total = dataDF.count
Total: Long = 45211
val success = subscribed / Total
success: Long = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast at least one of the variables to `Double`:

```
val success = subscribed.toDouble / Total
//success: Double = 0.11698480458295547
```